# Deserialization of JSON Object as array

Tags: c#, json, json.net

We have a JSON structure where we send an array of key value pairings from our server to the client.  For brevity and tidiness, we send the data like this:

```
"identification": {
    "lineItem/latestDate": "2013-04-28",
    "lineItem/destination": "test",
    "lineItem/quantity": "55"
}
```

instead of this:

```
"identification": [
    {
        "value": "test",
        "type": "lineItem/destination"
    },
    {
        "value": "2014-07-25",
        "type": "lineItem/latestDate"
    },
    {
        "value": "55",
        "type": "lineItem/quantity"
    }
]
```

The problem is our downstream client (who are processing the JSON using C#) say they cannot handle the first format, as the built in json.net functionality does not support it, and they do not know of another that can do it.

Is it possible to deserialize the first format using the built in JSON deserialization in C#?  Or does anyone know of another library that can take care of this?  I had a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22582532/c-sharp-json-net-array-like-object-deserialization-of-non-constant-name-object) and to me it looks possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, I found one more way of doing it and the good news is we do not have to change key names.

create a class at client side:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Dictionary<string,string> identification { get; set; }
}
```

Now, Deserialize it:

```
        string data = @"[
{
    ""identification"": {
        ""lineItem_latestDate"": ""2013-04-28"",
        ""lineItem_destination"": ""test"",
        ""lineItem_quantity"": ""55""
    }
},
{
    ""identification"": {
        ""lineItem_latestDate"": ""2013-04-28"",
        ""lineItem_destination"": ""test"",
        ""lineItem_quantity"": ""55""
    }
},
{
    ""identification"": {
        ""lineItem_latestDate"": ""2013-04-28"",
        ""lineItem_destination"": ""test"",
        ""lineItem_quantity"": ""55""
    }
}]";

List<RootObject> ob = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(data);
```

Bingo, We have done it again.

1) Now, ob object has desired values.

2) Works with array of values.

3) Supports iteration too.

Answer (score 4):

1) Given first JSON is not valid, requires left brace at starting and one extra comma to be removed from last.

2) If your client can use Newtonsoft.Json and you can use '_' instead of '/' in keys, because identifiers with '/' within name not supported in c#

Client Side:

create classes as

```
public class Identification
{
    public string lineItem_latestDate { get; set; }
    public string lineItem_destination { get; set; }
    public string lineItem_quantity { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Identification identification { get; set; }
}
```

NOTE: if you have more key/value pairs you can add more properties to class Identification

Now, Deserialize it as:

```
        string data = @"[
{
    ""identification"": {
        ""lineItem_latestDate"": ""2013-04-28"",
        ""lineItem_destination"": ""test"",
        ""lineItem_quantity"": ""55""
    }
},
{
    ""identification"": {
        ""lineItem_latestDate"": ""2013-04-28"",
        ""lineItem_destination"": ""test"",
        ""lineItem_quantity"": ""55""
    }
},
{
    ""identification"": {
        ""lineItem_latestDate"": ""2013-04-28"",
        ""lineItem_destination"": ""test"",
        ""lineItem_quantity"": ""55""
    }
}]";

        List<RootObject> ob = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(data);
```

Done, now ob object has values according to data.

Comment: Shouldn't the RootObject contain public List<Identification> identification {get;set;} ?

The JSON string should be deserialized as an array, according to the title.

Comment: thank for noticing that, I don't know how I skipped that.
If it is an array it should be List<Identification>, I'll update that

Comment: What happens to uncoded lineItems? I.e. if the consumer would like to iterate over the items?

Comment: this way is a bit faster than Dictionary<>

Comment: removed the erroneous comma, must have left that in when stripping away data to keep the question simple.

Answer (score 2):

Json.Net DOES support deserializing key-value pairings: you just need to use a `Dictionary<string, T>`, where `T` can be `object`, `JToken` or some other class that can receive the data values (`string` works in your case).  With a dictionary it is actually quite easy to deserialize and iterate over the values, as shown below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"
        {
            ""identification"": {
                ""lineItem/latestDate"": ""2013-04-28"",
                ""lineItem/destination"": ""test"",
                ""lineItem/quantity"": ""55"",
            }
        }";

        RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in obj.identification)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("type: " + kvp.Key);
            Console.WriteLine("value: " + kvp.Value);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}

class RootObject
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> identification { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
type: lineItem/latestDate
value: 2013-04-28

type: lineItem/destination
value: test

type: lineItem/quantity
value: 55
```

Comment: Deleted my post as this new information proves I was wrong. Thank you.